# Why can not use a String to initialize a StringBuilder object?

Tags: java, stringbuilder

```
StringBuilder sb = "asd";
```

In Java, this statement is obviously wrong. IDEs like eclipse will tell you that :

> cannot convert from String to StringBuilder

However, a `String` object could be initialized by `=` operator.

I'd like to know some reasons related with the **memory allocation**.

Comment: `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("asd");`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) is an Object and it needs to be constructed. You're getting the error because String is **not** a `StringBuilder`.

String is a special, it's designed to be between primitive and class<sup>1</sup>. You can assign a string literal directly into a String variable, instead of calling the constructor to create a String instance.

<sup>1</sup>[interesting topic](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J3d_String.html):

> The designers of Java decided to retain primitive types in an
>   object-oriented language, instead of making everything an object, so
>   as to improve the performance of the language. Primitives are stored
>   in the call stack, which require less storage spaces and are cheaper
>   to manipulate. On the other hand, objects are stored in the program
>   heap, which require complex memory management and more storage spaces.
>
> For performance reason, Java's String is designed to be in between a
>   primitive and a class.

More reading:

- [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5)
- [Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html)

Comment: Thanks! So this is because `String` is special in *Java*, Thus `=` operator could be used to construct a String object? Could you give me a url link or book reference to introduce more about `String` in Java?

Comment: @chainro You're welcome :) I've just posted a link that might help you.

Comment: -1 String also is an object with the difference that it is immutable and supports overloaded "=" operator. No more no less.

Comment: @lukasz1985 There is no operator overloading in Java. Also if you read again, you'll notice that I didn't say that String is not an Object.

Comment: It's overloaded from the language core as a default functionality. Operator overloading exist in this only one case.

Comment: You said that it's between a primitive and class. While string is Object and you can't say this, because it supports methods as every object does.

Comment: @lukasz1985 String **IS** a special case, read the article and you'll understand what they mean by "special case".

Comment: There is difference between saying that something is "designed o be in between a primitive and a class" and "being between primitive and class"

Comment: @lukasz1985 You're right, that's more clear and less confusing. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 9):

`"xxx"` is defined as [a String literal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5) by the specification of the language* and *is* a String object. So you can write:

```
String s = "abc";        //ok we got it
Object o = "abc";        //a String is an Object
CharSequence cs = "abc"; //a String is also a CharSequence
```

But a String is not a StringBuilder...

<sub>*Quote from the JLS: "A string literal is always of type `String`"</sub>

Answer (score 1):

[StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) is an object not a wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
String sb = "asd";
```

because you have a reference to a String literal being assigned to a variable reference. i.e. the types are the same.

You can't do this implicitly convert types or change an object with assignment in Java.

```
Object o = "asd";
```

Works because the String is an Object.

Answer (score 0):

String is not only a class but anything inside `""` is a JVM String and String object refers to that string.
So `String str="hello"` works.

But StringBuilder and other thousands of objects are not as special as `String` so they do not get initiialized likewise.

Answer (score 0):

In java the String is a **special type of class** u can define object for String like

```
String s = "xyz";
```

or

```
String s = new String("XYZ");
```

But **StringBuilde**r is just like a **normal class** and when u have to create a object for it you should use **new** keyword(Construct the object). HTH